# Phpxxxx.tmp file not getting deleted in Windows/temp folder

Tags: php

When I call API(get, patch etc) tmp file will be created and is not getting deleted in Windows/temp folder.
Every 5 min it increases by 2k -3k and not getting deleted.
Currently there are 65k temp file which are not deleted by server.

I cannot say it's because of API and the reason is few file size is 0kb and few contains API call details.

Kindly help me in this.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Windows never automatically cleans the `%TEMP%` directory by default.
Consider replacing your temporary files inside a subdirectory in the temp folder, and updating your code to purge old items.

[Developers using temporary files are expected to clean up after themselves.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364991(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Initially tmp file were getting deleted by its own.

Comment: You mean we need to write a separate code inorder to delete the  tmp file present in temp folder of window??

Comment: Starting with Windows 10 and Storage Sense, this is no longer correct: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63848110/67824