# Is Windows 10 or R itself deleting my temp directory?

Tags: r, temp

I saw the info on *finding* the name of my temp directory in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45894133/deleting-tmp-files).

The problem I'm having is that  my  Appdata/Local/temp/[Rtmpxxxx] directory is being deleted during an R session longer than 1 or 2 days.  I have turned off all automatic temp deletion actions that Windows 10  can take.  There's nothing in `Rprofile.site` or `.Renviron` related to temp directory or files.

Any ideas what I need to turn off or modify to keep the Rtmp directory from being deleted?

Comment: Could you elaborate on exactly what `automatic temp deletion` you turned off and how? Also, I believe Storage Sense will self-activate in cases of low disk space - what is your disk space situation (on the %APPDATA% disk)?

Comment: @OhadSchneider definitely not a disk space issue - I had less than 50% usage.  This being 18 months later, I fear I can't recall specifically what I turned off.   I did not know about "Storage Sense, but I see my CorporateOverlords forced it to "During low free disk space"  .  that shouldn't have mattered, but....

Comment: Storage Sense doesn't necessarily run only on low disk space, it can be configured to run as often as every day. Could you check how your corporate admins configured it? https://imgur.com/a/JQaIeuE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move your temp directory to another folder (outside the win10 temp folder)
e.g. with `write("TMP = '<your-desired-tempdir>'", file=file.path(Sys.getenv('R_USER'), '.Renviron'))`

If it is still being deleted, it is rather unlikely that Win10 deletes it.

### edit by the OP

Depending on [something mysterious], the same command above should be used to create `TEMP`  and `TMPDIR`  as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107206/change-temporary-directory)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683831/limitations-of-temp-directory-in-windows

Comment: Hi - sorry for the delay -- I will try this out and report back.

Comment: So far -- 24 hours -- looks like   ~/Rtmp  is not being deleted, so I blame it on something typically braindead in Windows10 .    I would like to know if there's a way to stop the OS from doing this, but... whatever.

Comment: I am glad to hear. Did you move the temp DIR?

Comment: you bet I did!   :-)